# In 1940 Ireland, could a man with a venereal disease obtain a condom legally?

Tags: medical, ireland, history

My questions arise from a scenario in *Finnegans Wake* by James Joyce, published in 1939, and pertain to Irish contraception and medical laws around or before 1939.

Contraception was [illegal in Ireland from 1935 until 1980](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contraception_in_the_Republic_of_Ireland), when it was legalised with strong restrictions, later loosened. Owning and using contraceptive devices and pills was *never* prohibited, however, from 1935, it was illegal to sell or to import them.

- In 1940 Ireland, could a man with a venereal disease obtain a condom legally?

Comment: I would think that given that the world war was on, the demand from nations for rubber would have made the supply of... er... rubbers in much of the world.   While the Republic of Ireland was neutral during WWII, it would likely have suffered in part due to the Battle of the Atlantic... though I am reminded of a crude joke about the invention of the condums that relies on it not being made from rubber.

Comment: We do see a "man's gummy article" next to the bed after love making.

Comment: @hszmv: *Finnegans Wake* was actually published before the war broke out.

Comment: @hszmv the mobilization and deployment around the world of millions of men greatly increased both demand for   **and production of** prophylactics. Soldiers with VD make poor soldiers and generals know this - they made sure condoms were widely available

Comment: @DaleM:  Ireland was Neutral, meaning it wasn't involved in WWII.

Comment: @hszmv Ireland is part of the world that saw this increased supply